# root values of simultaneous nonlinear equations in R

Tags: r

I've been trying to code this problem:
https://sg.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110127015240AA9RjyZ

I believe there is a R function somewhere to solve for the root values of the  following equations:

```
(x+3)^2 + (y-50)^2 = 1681
(x-11)^2 + (y+2)^2 = 169
(x-13)^2 + (y-34)^2 = 625
```

I tried using the 'solve' function but they're only for linear equations(?)

Also tried 'nls'

```
dt = data.frame(a=c(-3,11,13), b = c(50, -2, 34), c = c(1681,169,625))
nls(c~(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2, data = dt, start = list(x = 1, y = 1))
```

but getting an error all the time. (and yes I already tried changing the max iteration)

> Error in nls(c ~ (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2, data = dt, start = list(x = 1,  : 
>    number of iterations exceeded maximum of 50

how do you solve the root values in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nls` does not work with zero residual data -- see `?nls` where this is mentioned.  `nlxb` in the nlmrt package is mostly similar to `nls` in terms of input arguments and does support zero residual data. Using `dt` from the question just replace `nls` with `nlxb`:

```
library(nlmrt)
nlxb(c~(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2, data = dt, start = list(x = 1, y = 1))
```

giving:

```
nlmrt class object: x 
residual sumsquares =  2.6535e-20  on  3 observations
    after  5    Jacobian and  6 function evaluations
  name            coeff          SE       tstat      pval      gradient    JSingval   
x                      6      7.21e-12  8.322e+11  7.649e-13  -1.594e-09       96.93  
y                     10     1.864e-12  5.366e+12  1.186e-13   -1.05e-08       22.45
```

Comment: Im leaning towards this solution as I have numerous variables and i only need to find the best possible point.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot always solve three equations for two variables.You can solve two equations for two variables and test if the solution satisfies the third equation.

Use package `nleqslv` as follows.

```
library(nleqslv)

f1 <- function(z) {
    f <- numeric(2)
    x <- z[1]
    y <- z[2]
    f[1] <- (x+3)^2 + (y-50)^2 - 1681
    f[2] <- (x-11)^2 + (y+2)^2 - 169
    f
}

f2 <- function(z) {
    x <- z[1]
    y <- z[2]
    (x-13)^2 + (y-34)^2 - 625   
}

zstart <- c(0,0)
z1 <- nleqslv(zstart,f1)
z1
f2(z1$x)
```

which gives you the following output:

```
>z1
$x
[1]  6 10

$fvec
[1] 7.779818e-09 7.779505e-09

$termcd
[1] 1

$message
[1] "Function criterion near zero"

$scalex
[1] 1 1

$nfcnt
[1] 9

$njcnt
[1] 1

$iter
[1] 9

>f2(z1$x)
[1] 5.919242e-08
```

So a solution has been found and the solution follows from the vector `z$x`. Inserting z$x in function `f2` also gives almost zero.

So a solution has been found.

You could also try package `BB`.

Comment: The two equation for two variable rule does not hold in this case as the equations are quadratic.

Comment: You need a third equation though to derive the true point. Having two equations would provide two sets of points. But i like this one.

Comment: You should explain that statement. I simply don't believe that. The two equations describe circles. They intersect at 1 or 2 points or not at all.

Comment: @geodex. You are correct for 2 quadratic equations. As is stated in my comment 0,1 or 2 solutions. According to the original problems  in this case there 1 solution. If one doesn't know then you could use function `searchZeros` from package `nleqslv`

Comment: @Bathsheba. Your second comment does not explain why the`two equation for two variables rule` does not hold. You are confusing the number of solutions (0,1,2) with the number of variables in two equations.

Comment: Not really, The system is not uniquely solved until you have a third equation (i.e. a third circle), unless you have the "just touching" case. But even then of course the system might not be solvable in real space (e.g. the case where the circles are disjoint, or the "Venn diagram" case).

Comment: Cheers Bhas. Im looking for the intersection of the three circles. I assumed that they all intersect at a common point which i failed to mention. I do wonder if you can determine the common point using a matrix of constants on BBsolve or nleqslv.

Comment: Note that disjoint finite circles cannot intersect at a common point (but don't ask me to prove it ;-) )

Answer (score -2):

Just go through **rootSolve** package and you will be done:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rootSolve/vignettes/rootSolve.pdf